# Compare item 1 list one to item 1 list 2 then item 2 list 2 and so forth. Can't iterate properly

Tags: python, list, nested, iteration

I need help with the concept. I'm new to Python.

I know I need a nested for loop, but the lists are two different sizes. I want to loop the .dat file and check if it matches an item in the .csv file. The thing is something like this doesn’t compare very well.

```
for row in list1:  
    print(row)  
    for row2 in list2:  
        print(row2[1])  
        if row == row2[1]:  
            print(“match”)
        else:
            print(row2[1] + ' ' + row
```

)

This will spit out output like this:

```
list1-item1
list2-item1
list2-item1 list1-item1
list2-item2
list2-item2 list1-item1
list2-item3 
list2-item3 list1-item1
```

I can see it's not iterating properly due to where I placed the prints. I have two CSV files I'm trying to compare (one line delimited '\n' and one comma delimited). I'm trying to find items from list1 that exist in list2, but I can't seem to get it to iterate past the first item in list1? It would be easier if there was an eof in Python. I know I'm making a dumb mistake somewhere, I just can't figure out where.

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialize `list1` and `list2`?

Comment: The code and question you've posted don't match the title.  Let's imagine two lists `[1,2,3,4,5]` and `[1,3,2,4,5,7,8]`.  Do you want to "compare each item by index" e.g 1 to 1 (match), 2 to 3, 3 to 2, 4 to 4 (match) and so on...  Or, do you want to answer " look at 1 from list1 - is it in list2 (match), look at 2 from list1 - isit in list2 (match) and so on..." ? Put another way - in my example would you want to see 3 matches, or 5?  Also, as per mattm - can we see the list initialisation - because the `row2[1]` is very unusual

Answer (score 0):

Hi your problem is the addition of indexes in the if clause and in the print clause. You don't need to specify an index, even more, you shouldn't because this leads to unintended behavior. When getting values in a for loop from a list, each iteration the defined variable (row, row2) will contain only the subsequent item from the list. You should change your code to the following:

```python
for row in list1:  
    print(row)  
    for row2 in list2:  
        print(row2)  
        if row == row2:  
            print(“match”)
        else:
            print(row2 + ' ' + row
```